# Algebra has me hitting a wall

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Math is not my strong suit. As far as I can tell, this is what I'm looking to solve.

```
A+B=C and B=C*D
```

If one knows what A and D equal, can one determine the value of B and C?

So far, I've tried:

```
A+B=C
A+C*D=C
C*D=C-A
C*D-C=-A
A=C-C*D
```

And then I get stuck. Also:

```
A+B=C
B=C-A
C*D=C-A
C=(C-A)/D
1=((C-A)/D)/C
```

Stuck again.

Is this doable?

Comment: So close.... You got to $CD-C=A$; can you do something to the left side?

Comment: It's killing me - I can't figure out how to get C alone on the left side!

Comment: Sorry, I meant $CD-C=-A$; now do something **just** to the left side.

Comment: Hint --- what if you had $(C)(73)-C$?

Comment: Still wrestling with it - even if I divide by D, I get C-C/D=-A/D and I'm no better off then I was before...

Comment: Try using $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ or $a(b-c) = ab - ac$.

Comment: HINT --- WHAT IF YOU HAD $(C)(73)-C$?

Comment: So if `CD-C=-A` then `C(D-1)=-A` then `C=-A/(D-1)`  Is that right?

Comment: Assuming $D$ isn't $1$, yes.

Comment: Eric, once you have figured the whole thing out, you can post it as answer, and then, later, accept it. That helps cut down the Unanswered Questions queue.

Comment: Thanks Alraxite and Gerry - gave credit to Samrat (because he gave the answer outright) but you guys led me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From eqn. 1 put the value of $C$ in eqn. 2 and you get \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
B=&(A+B)D \\
\Rightarrow \ B-BD=&AD\\ 
\Rightarrow  B=\frac{AD}{1-D} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}. The last step follows by taking the $BD$ in RHS to LHS and then taking some common factor. Since you know $A,\ D$, so you know B. Now put this value of $B$ in eqn. 1 to get $$C=A+\frac{AD}{1-D}=\frac{A}{1-D}$$

Comment: Why not let OP work this out? He's so close....

Comment: Ok, yeah true @GerryMyerson